# how to add a new weka classification algorithm to weka library

Tags: machine-learning, weka, decision-tree

I want to use some classification algorithm by weka(like c4.5, ID3) but I dont know how to add them to weka! Are they available on weka? and if these algorithm are not available how can I add them?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search led me to the package description page of [weka.classifiers.trees](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/trees/package-summary.html) where you can read that both mentioned classifiers are included in weka.

1. [ID3 javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/trees/Id3.html)
2. C4.5 is named J48 in weka: [J48 javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html)

Hopefully this answers your question, if not, please provide some more details of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package manager assoicated with Weka known as the 'Weka package manager' you should see it on the top left of the Weka GUI chooser. You need to go tools and then select 'Package Manager'. The Weka package manager contains a lists of algorithms and packages maintained by Weka.You simply need to search for the algorithm that you are planning to choose within the search bar of the package manager, once you've done this it will be installed you can see in the install option given in Weka package manager. To activate the algorithm all you need to do is go on to 'toggle load' which will prompt you to restart weka and it will be activated for use to use in Explorer section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [simpleEducationalLearningSchemes](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/simpleEducationalLearningSchemes/index.html) package through Weka's package manager in order to get ID3.

J48 (Weka's C4.5 implementation) comes with the base installation of Weka already and does not require installing a package.

See also the Weka wiki articles on [packages](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/).